# What type should you store the date in a database?

Tags: date, types, gql

Currently I'm storing it as a String, but got problems using it when it comes to querying by date with GQL.

```
Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss, z");
String todayDate = formatter.format(date);
```

The query:

```
"SELECT FROM SomeTable p WHERE date = 01/01/2011"
```

Error:
Exception:

> org.datanucleus.store.appengine.query.DatastoreQuery$UnsupportedDatastoreFeatureException:
>   Problem with query : Right side of expression is
>   composed of unsupported components.
>   Left:
>   org.datanucleus.query.expression.Literal,
>   Op: / , Right:
>   DyadicExpression{Literal{5} /
>   Literal{11}}

How can I search by date?

Comment: check this article out http://unix4lyfe.org/time/ it's about what every developer should know about date and time

Comment: @Atzoya That does not say much re dates and I would say is wrong if you deal with dates not timestamps. If a date use a date type as it deals with adding days, no complexity of timezone or leap seconds etc - a offset in seconds is more complex to add a date. But as the reference says if you need a timestamp then things are different,

Comment: I get what you are saying Mark, and you are right if you need to handle timstamps or date-times with a more specific need in mind, you should store the datetime in a number format, otherwise the date type should be enough

Answer (score 0):

Always as a date - the database should check on the types of data that it stores thus making sure the data is what it says. the information about what type is known on the insert so check it then rather than later when none has any idea of what the correct value should have been.

the error you are getting is probably not due to this but because the date in the query needs to be made a date if types are correct or if a string needs to be as a single-quoted string see [GQL Reference](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference.html)
e.g.

```
"SELECT FROM SomeTable p WHERE date = '01/01/2011'"
```

but what date is 06/07/2011 ? I think it is today 6th July, others 7th June.  So even if you use strings use the ISO format 2011-07-06 A date type will hide this detail making it easier. Note that GQL only uses the ISO form so even if you got the command to have the date in a string it would fail.

but better as

```
SELECT FROM SomeTable p WHERE date = DATE( 2011, 1, 1)
```

Comment: Ah yeah, the single quotes did work.

If I changed the date type to Date, how would I get the date without the time as a Date type?

Comment: Ah that is Java - following the Unix way of having timestamps - just set the hours, mins, secs to 0, and use DataProperty not Time Poperty.

Comment: btw - SELECT FROM SomeTable p WHERE date = DATE( 2011, 1, 1) - doesn't work for me, unsupported <date> method...?